# How do I do a use a map function to create a custom hash from an array in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have some JavaScript:

```
var $things = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "image": "one.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "image": "two.png"
  },
];
```

It gets converted to a Perl array (`$thingsJSON` is a string representation of the above):

```
 my $coder = JSON::XS->new->utf8;
 my $things = $coder->decode($thingsJSON);
```

A want a map function on `$things` that will return a collection (`$args`) that looks like this:

```
(
  image => "one.png",
  image => "two.png"
)
```

I want to be able to pass the above as `$args` to another function:

`$Bar->find($args)`

Comment: That wouldn't be a hash; a hash never has two items with the same key. Do you just want an array containing the list of key/value pairs?

Comment: Yes, an array of objects (hashes?)

Comment: An array of hashes is what you already have. Do you just want to remove the `id` keys then?

Comment: yeah and change the `image` key to `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you actually want is an array containing a list you can pass to that function, which expects key/value pairs, this would work:

```
@args = map { (image => $_->{image}) } @$things;
```

for clarity, this is the same as

```
@args = map { ('image', $_->{image}) } @$things;
```

that is, `map` is just returning a list where all of the even-numbered elements are the string `"image"` and all of the odd-numbered elements are the value of the `image` key of some element in `@$things`.

Comment: wow. this looks like it might work. tbh i'm learning perl, so the list concept is kind of blowing me away. but the first pass looks sweet. I'll give it a try and accept if it works. Thank you!

Comment: i used your line first line but i'm getting a syntax error: `near "} @"`

Comment: maybe an older version of Perl?

Comment: @MartinCortez no, my fault. Fixed.

Comment: as it turned out I needed an array of hashes, so i went with: `@args = map { {image => $_->{image}} } @$things;`

Comment: @MartinCortez: But `$things` is already an array of hashes containing exactly that information. You're wastefully duplicating your data

Comment: Almost exactly. It does remove the `id` elements. That's be cheaper to do using `delete($_->{id}) for @args;`